# SQL convert string to date format 112

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, date-conversion

I have an input date and I need to convert it to format 112 (yyyymmdd) for use later on in my SQL statement.

```
declare @day varchar(10)

set @day = '6/21/2013'

select @day
```

I've done this before...IDK if it's because I'm on SQL 2000 for this project that it's not working now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would convert it to a `datetime` first, then to the format that you want:

```
declare @day varchar(10)

set @day = '6/21/2013'

select convert(varchar(10), cast(@day as datetime), 112);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16195)

Comment: I was using a request parameter (not manually set like in example) and it was having issues with quotes. Thanks this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code from this novice user of this site.

```
declare @day varchar(10);

set @day = '6/21/2013';
select convert(date,@day,112);
```

Comment: This gives me the error code: *The input character string does not follow style 112, either change the input character string or use a different style.*